# SwiftUI custom nested array ForEach

Tags: arrays, foreach, swiftui

So i have a nested array of a model:

```
let models = [[ButtonModel]]
    struct ButtonModel: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let value: String
        let style: ColorStyle
        
        init(_ value: String, _ style: ColorStyle) {
            self.value = value
            self.style = style
        }
    }
```

Then i want to add this as a grid so i have a VStack in which i loop x amount of  HStacks with buttons in it.

But because of some reason i get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[[ButtonModel]]' to expected argument type 'Binding'

> Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred

```
VStack {
    ForEach(viewModel.buttons, id: \.self) { buttons in
                HStack(spacing: GridPoints.x2) {
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(buttons) { buttonValue in
                        if buttonValue == "/" {
                            imageButton(for: Asset.Image) { viewModel.addValue(buttonValue) }
                        } else {
                            Button(buttonValue, action: { viewModel.addValue(buttonValue) })
                                .buttonStyle(customFont: .h3)
                                .background(Color.backgroundColor)
                                .styleText(style: TextStyle.h3)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(GridPoints.x1)
            }
    }
```

Anyone know what this error is?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

It looks like you made a mistake when using `buttonValue` too.

You should use it like this

```swift
ForEach(buttons) { button in
    if button.value == "/" {
        imageButton(for: Asset.Image) { viewModel.addValue(button.value) }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

`ForEach` requires an array whose every element is `Identifiable` (or telling which one is the `id` to use using `id: \.something`).

Your problem is that if you use an array of array, this means that every element of the outer array is another array which is **NOT** conforming to `Identifiable`.

If you use `ForEach(arrayOfArray, id: \.self)`, on the other hand, your telling that the identifier will be each element of the outer array that must conform to `Hashable`. `Array` conform to `Hashable` if its element does. So try to change your struct to

```swift
struct ButtonModel: Identifiable, Hashable { ... }
```

### Alternate solution

You could change your structure to

```swift
struct ButtonsGroup: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let buttons: [ButtonModel]
}
```

Then you will be using it like this:

```swift
let groups = [ButtonsGroup]()

ForEach(groups) { group in
    ForEach(group.buttons) { button in
        Text(button.value)
    }
}
```